# Simple present used to describe past events as a list of actions?

Tags: grammar

In relation to you not meeting me at the train station yesterday:

'I wake up early, travel all that way, wait for you in the rain, and you don't meet me!'

Is this not the simple present being used with a past meaning?

Comment: It can mean the future, too, as in *He **takes** the bar exam Thursday* or *When I **die** you **can have** the furniture.*

Comment: *Bleak House* is written largely in the present tense. Er, was written.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Essentially, yes. As in various languages, the simple present can be used to denote a "past action as though unfolding before your eyes".